How to iterate and get all the values of a dictionary into another list of dictionary with different keys
I am trying to iterate through a list of dictionaries and fetch the values of 2 keys and write the values to another list of dictionaries which has another key. The below is the output list that I am trying to write to.
post_obj = [
    {
        "city": place["place"],
        "display": place["seq"]
    }
]

Input:
data = [
    {'place': 'San Jose', 'seq': 1},
    {'place': 'San Diego', 'seq': 2},
    {'place': 'San Fransisco', 'seq': 3}
]

Code:
post_obj = []
if len(data) > 0:
    for id in data:
        post_obj = [
            {
                "city": id["place"],
                "display": id["seq"]
            }
        ]
else:
    post_obj["areas"] = []

Output:
[{'cityName': 'Inline', 'displayOrder': 3}]

Expected Output:
[{'cityName': 'San Jose', 'displayOrder': 1}, {'cityName': 'San Diego', 'displayOrder': 2}, {'cityName': 'San Fransisco', 'displayOrder': 3}]

I don't know what I'm missing but I'm unable to get the first 2 cities in the list. Any help or input is appreciated. Thank you!

Do not use id, it will shadow the already built-in function

If I run your code with your example, I get a different output.

Why did you initialize an empty list at the beginning if you were later going to initialize it again? Can you explain what do you think is happening in each iteration of the for loop? How to debug small programs

@IgnatiusReilly id can be a perfectly good name, and the built-in is really rarely used. (Just earlier today I saw someone say they disabled syntax highlighting for built-ins in their IDE because they use the name id so frequently.)

@nocomment The OP is obviously at a early stage of learning. Shadowing built-ins is.... well you know, we're all consenting adults! But IMO the OP would benefit from focusing on style and good practices at this point.

You can use a list comprehension like this:
data = [
    {'place': 'San Jose', 'seq': 1},
    {'place': 'San Diego', 'seq': 2},
    {'place': 'San Fransisco', 'seq': 3}
]

post_obj = [{'cityName': item['place'], 'displayOrder': item['seq']} for item in data]

print(post_obj)
[{'cityName': 'San Jose', 'displayOrder': 1}, {'cityName': 'San Diego', 'displayOrder': 2}, {'cityName': 'San Fransisco', 'displayOrder': 3}]


You are overwriting your list instead of appending to it, thus only leaving the last item in the list. Try this instead:
post_obj = []
if len(data) > 0:
    for id in data:
        post_obj.append(
            {
                "cityName": id["place"],
                "displayOrder": id["seq"]
            }
        )
else:
    post_obj.append({"areas": []})


It would help if you tried this,
if len(data) > 0:
    for item in data:
        post_obj.append(
            {
                "cityName": item["place"],
                "displayOrder": item["seq"]
            }
        )
else:
    post_obj.append({"areas": []})

print(post_obj)

Here is the output,


Please do not upload images of code/data/errors.

But I added the code itself also. I wanted to show the output with the code that I answer.

Copy and paste the output. You can add it as a comment to your code. I can't see right now the output in my desktop screen without clicking the linked image. I couldn't see it in my phone for sure. Please check the link in my previous comment.

I wanted to show the output, the code is on top.

small typo in code, you need to append to list, so use "+=" instead of just "=" and you code should run fine.
post_obj = []
if len(data) > 0:
    for id in data:
        post_obj += [
            {
                "city": id["place"],
                "display": id["seq"]
            }
        ]
else:
    post_obj["areas"] += []

